# Diophantine Equation : $x+y+z=3$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

Solve, in integers, the system of equations.

$x+y+z=3$

$x^3+y^3+z^3=3$

I'm not sure how to approach this question, as I have only dealt with linear diophantine equations.

Comment: $(1,1,1)$ pops up - the hard part is showing there are no other solutions

Comment: Yeah, there are other solutions

Comment: Really? I'm surprised ... have you found an example?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee $(4,4,-5)$ and its permutations

Comment: Very nice - I hope somebody gives a complete solution, I am interested

Comment: I believe those are the only solutions, however, I'm not sure how I would show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating $z$ from 
$$x+y+z=3,\quad x^3+y^3+z^3=3$$
gives
$$\begin{align}&x^3+y^3+(3-x-y)^3=3\\&\Rightarrow x^3+y^3+27-27x+9x^2-x^3-27y+18xy-3x^2y+9y^2-3xy^2-y^3-3=0\\&\Rightarrow 24-27x+9x^2-27y+18xy-3x^2y+9y^2-3xy^2=0\\&\Rightarrow 8-9x+3x^2-9y+6xy-x^2y+3y^2-xy^2=0\\&\Rightarrow (3-y)x^2-x(3-y)^2-3y(3-y)=-8\\&\Rightarrow (3-y)(x^2-x(3-y)-3y)=-8\\&\Rightarrow (y-3)(x^2-x(3-y)-3y)=8\\&\Rightarrow (y-3)(x+y)(x-3)=8\end{align}$$

So, we have
$$\small(y-3,(x+y)(x-3))=(1,8),(2,4),(4,2),(8,1),(-1,-8),(-2,-4),(-4,-2),(-8,-1).$$

Now checking if each of these is sufficient gives that the followings are the only solutions :
$$(x,y,z)=(1,1,1),(-5,4,4),(4,-5,4),(4,4,-5).$$

Comment: None of those are solutions, all extranneous, there has to be an easier way

Comment: All of the solutions above are extranneous @mathlove

Comment: @GC10101: Sorry, but I don't think so. $(y-3,(x+y)(x-3))=(-2,-4)$, i.e. $y-3=-2$ and $(x+y)(x-3)=-4$, for example, gives $(x,y)=(1,1)$. What I wrote is the necessary condition. So, all you need is to check if each of them is sufficient. I agree that there might be an easy way.

Comment: @GC10101: As you conjectured, $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1),(-5,4,4),(4,-5,4),(4,4,-5)$ are the only solutions.

Comment: @GC10101, I don't see why there should be an "easier" solution than this. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58188/are-nontrivial-integer-solutions-known-for-x3y3z3-3 for status ***without the restriction*** $x+y+z=3$

Comment: Yeah, I have found a much easier way to complete this though.

Comment: @GC10101 Could you share the easier way with us?

Answer (score 0):

(This is only a partial answer to the question.)

First, we have:
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = x + y + z = 3.$$

Assume that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all positive.

Note that, by the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality:
$$3 = x + y + z = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \geq 3\sqrt[3]{{x^3}{y^3}{z^3}} = 3xyz,$$
so that $xyz \leq 1$.

Since $x$, $y$, and $z$ are (assumed to be positive) integers, the only solution that works is $x = y = z = 1$.

Comment: $x,y,z$ could be negative.

Comment: Hold on, let me address that issue.

Comment: The solutions could be negative as well @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris